# Conditional Count and group by with realtime data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I was able to find [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1288058/1654121) and [close-match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11006449/1654121) questions regarding my query. But I want to know if there are better ways of doing the same.

I have a database table which is being populated by call to a web-service end-point. The end-point is called when certain event occurs and a new record is inserted to this table. The events take place in real-time and there is no set frequency or pattern of occurrence of the events.

The table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTbl(id int, type nvarchar(10), timestamp datetime, category nvarchar(50));
```

I am fetching data from the table as:

```
SELECT category,
COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'sent' THEN 1 END) sent,
COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'received' THEN 1 END) received,
COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'blocked' THEN 1 END) blocked,
COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'opened' THEN 1 END) opened
FROM MyTbl
WHERE timestamp >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND timestamp < '2013-02-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY category
```

The details about the `database schema`, `sample data` and `select-query` for the report is available [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5efcb/3).

Given that the:

> 1. data is fed into the table in real-time
> 2. table will store huge volume of data approx. 10,00,000+ records
> 3. structure of the report-query will not change
> 4. data would be filtered on category, date-from and date-to (all are optional parameters)
> 5. time is not relevant, only date part is

Will it be a good idea to run a scheduled task that would run periodically and update a new table with values from `MyTbl`? The new table would look similar to the report query:

```
Date | Category | Sent | Received | Blocked | Opened
```

and this table would be queried by applying category and date filters.

Negatives to this approach:

> 1. We still have to maintain data on daily basis
> 2. We still have to apply GROUP BY and SUM
> 3. There may be more database operations required than the original approach
> 4. We will not get all the data that comes in real-time.

Positives to this approach:

> 1. May speed-up the records fetching from the database which can speed-up the process of display, sorting and paging

Is this a viable approach?
Are there any other ways to speed up the process? Please help!

Comment: you can also try stored procedure . they execute much faster then sql query

Comment: @sourabhdevpura, this is executing using stored procedure only. I used the SQL query to make it simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a viable approach.

You may also want to consider reconfiguring your query as a `PIVOT`.

```
select *
from 
    (select [date],category, [type] 
       from yourtable 
       where timestamp between '2013-01-01' and '2013-02-01') d
pivot 
(count (type) for [type] in (sent,blocked,received,opened)) p
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This query executes faster than the original query by ~37 times! It was hard for me to believe but now I know it is awesome. Thanks again!